# In-Browser software for easily creating chord sheets

Tags: chords, software, lead-sheets

Is there any in-browser web app where one can easily create chord sheets (I'm thinking of more like a graphical approach; not just ChordPro) and transpose them? I've done a bit of research now and can't find anything.

Comment: Hello Tobias, these  kind of questions are usually off topic on this site. I think it'd be a better fit on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a bummer, since I believe users of this site would have much more of an idea about this. Do you think there's a way to reframe my question so it's not off-topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software recommendations are off-topic.